# how to filter a search in the database by specific column?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to filter the search in sqlite. I would like to select only the rows that have a certain argument in the column.

with the following code I get the return of all the rows through a array constructed by the function queueAll ()

fun readFileFromSQLite(): ArrayList {

```
    var fileName = ArrayList<String>()

    var cursor = queueAll()

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast) {
            //val name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(countyname))
            var message_uuid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_y1))
            var message_time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_y2))
            var message_from = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_y3))
            var message_to = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_y4))
            var message_subject = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_y5))
            var message_body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_y6))

            fileName.add(message_body)
            cursor.moveToNext()
        }



        }
        cursor.close()

    return fileName
}

fun queueAll(): Cursor {
    val columns = arrayOf<String>("message_uuid", "message_time","message_from","message_to","message_subject","message_body")
    val db = readableDatabase

    val comp = "comprimido"
    return db.query(CHAT, columns,  null, null, null, null, null)
  //  return db.rawQuery("select * from CHAT where message_from=web_anon , null);
}
```

Now, I'd like to extract only the rows that have the message_from column with a specific string. My attempt by:
return db.rawQuery ("select * from CHAT where message_from = web_anon, null) returns error

Comment: Cant you just add if message_from==anon in front of filename.add ? I mean yiu dont even say what the error is and where you put that line, so this is the best i can do.

Comment: If the string is actually "web_anon" you should wrap it into single quotes.

Comment: Thanks @IcedLance an Giorgos.  The two forms work. I will be with the second option, already selecting in the database exactly the data I want, using the single quotes as suggested by Giorgos.

Answer (score 0):

Working. The correct select is:

`return db.rawQuery("select * from CHAT where message_from= 'web_anon' , null)` with single quotes on argument.

A second option is add this condition: `if (message_from==web_anon) { filename.add(message_body)}`

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of using [`rawQuery()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D)) is this:

```
db.rawQuery("select * from CHAT where message_from= ?" , arrayOf("web_anon"))
```

The 2nd argument is an array of strings passed to the 1st argument which is the query itself and each `?` placeholder is replaced by each item of the array.
This way you don't have to worry about the data type of the columns and is also sql-injection safe.